# Configuring DataSource and Registering it with JNDI

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

I follow up the java doc [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)for datasource.

I am not understanding the below code snippt.

I create a connectionpooldatasource and register with jndi.

```
cpds.setServerName("creamer");
cpds.setDatabaseName("COFFEEBREAK");
cpds.setPortNumber(9040);
cpds.setDescription("Connection pooling for " + "COFFEEBREAK DBMS");

Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.bind("jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB", cpds);
```

Now we can retrive this connection pool data source

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup("jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB");
```

I create an another datasource and register it.

```
com.applogic.PooledDataSource ds = new 
com.applogic.PooledDataSource();
ds.setDescription("produces pooled connections to COFFEEBREAK");
ds.setDataSourceName("jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB");

Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.bind("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB", ds);
```

Now we can retrive this connection pool data source

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB");
```

I am not clear about setDataSourceName.

We add ConnectionPoolDS into PoolDataSource.

when we retrive the datasource

```
 ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB");
```

then the data soruce return from here is PoolDataSource type or ConnectionPoolDS type?.

Answer (score 1):

using this

> jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB JNDI
>   you are directly pointing to COFFEEBREAK database.

in  second JNDI

> jdbc/fastCoffeeDB

you are using following statement

ds.setDataSourceName("jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB");

In the above you are pointing old JNDI name, this means you are indirectly points to COFFEEBREAK database

**so from statement
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB");
you will get ConnectionPoolDS.**

Comment: what is the reason of doing this.Why we create an extra PoolDataSource if we cant use it.By using     jdbc/pool/fastCoffeeDB  & jdbc/fastCoffeeDB if we get ConnectionPoolDS each time.

Comment: @jogendra if you will read complete page answer is there A basic DataSource implementation produces standard Connection objects that are not pooled or used in a distributed transaction.
A DataSource implementation that supports connection pooling produces Connection objects that participate in connection pooling, that is, connections that can be recycled.